# Integrate complex function over $\mathbb{C}^2$

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, complex-integration

I have a question in mind and I would appreciate your help. Usually in complex analysis we consider integrals of the form $\int_\gamma f(z) dz$ where $\gamma $ is a contour and $f:\mathbb{C}\rightarrow\mathbb{C}$.

What if $g:\mathbb{C}^2\rightarrow\mathbb{C}$, and we want to find the integral $\int_U g(z_1,z_2) \;dz_1dz_2$ where $U\subset\mathbb{C}^2$ is an open subset? How can we evaluate this integral? Can we apply for example the change of variables formula in the same way we apply it for $\mathbb{R^n}$?

For example: $g(z_1, z_2)=\frac{1}{z_1 (z_1+z_2)}.$

Thank you!

Comment: If it's an open subset of $\mathbb{C}^2$, you need four differentials in the integral, $\int_U g(z_1,z_2)\,dz_1\,d\overline{z}_1\,dz_2\,d\overline{z}_2$ for example. You can identify $\mathbb{C}^2$ with $\mathbb{R}^4$, and then use the usual real methods. Additionally, you can use the complex notation like I did above, which sometimes makes things easier (to see) than the real notation.

Comment: OK, I can see the idea here, but I don't know how to identify $\mathbb{C}^2 $with $\mathbb{R}^4.$ For example, could you please show me how we do that for the particular $g$  above? If you use complex notation, how can you actually compute such an integral?

Comment: You map $(z_1,z_2) \mapsto (x_1,y_1, x_2,y_2)$ or $(z_1,z_2) \mapsto (x_1,x_2,y_1,y_2)$, where $z_k = x_k + iy_k$. The generalisation to identifying $\mathbb{C}^n$ with $\mathbb{R}^{2n}$ should be clear. Your example function isn't particularly nice to integrate. If $U$ is nice, you can evaluate the integral as an iterated integral at least in principle (I don't think you get something nice, and maybe you can't even get it in closed form).

Comment: @JoeAaron: The two-variable analogue of integrating over a complex contour would be integrating over a surface such as a torus (a product of contours) rather than integrating over an open set. For that you'd parametrize your surface, just as you parametrize a complex contour, and express the double integral over a parameter domain in $\mathbf{R}^{2}$. (The domain of your $g$ has the homotopy type of a real $2$-torus, incidentally.)

Comment: @Daniel : Since the area element is equal to $dx_1 dy_1=\frac{\sqrt{-1}}{2} dz_1 d\bar{z}_1$, why do we ommit the $\sqrt{-1}/2$ in the integral?

Comment: @JoeAaron We don't omit it,  one needs the factors when switching from $dx_k\,dy_k$ to $dz_k\, d\overline{z}_k$ or vice versa to compute the same integral. But of course $\int_U g(z_1,z_2)\,dz_1\,d\overline{z}_1\, dz_2\,d\overline{z}_2$ is as valid an integral as $\int_U g(z_1,z_2)\,dx_1\,dy_1 \,dx_2\,dy_2$; these integrals just differ by a factor of $-4$.

Comment: now I see, thank you really for your help.